# Laravel 5: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation, foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am building an upvote/downvote system in Laravel 5 using AJAX.
I am also using this jquery plugin to display the voting button: https://github.com/janosgyerik/jquery-upvote

But I keep getting this error. It also appears that it is ignoring the `post_id` field completely (due to my relations?) and it is not submitting any value from the buttons in the `value` field.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`laravel_5`.`votes`, CONSTRAINT `votes_post_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`post_id`) REFERENCES `posts` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `votes`
>   (`value`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, 2,
>   2015-09-14 22:02:11, 2015-09-14 22:02:11))

I've tried a couple of things, first I used `save()` instead of `create()` like so

```
Auth::user()->votes()->save($request->all());
```

But that gave another error

> ErrorException in HasOneOrMany.php line 210: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-5\app\Http\Controllers\VotesController.php on
>   line 63 and defined

Even though I was including `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` in the controller.

I have also tried using this instead

```
App\User::find(Auth::user()->id)->votes()->save($request->all());
```

But I got `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\User' not found` even though I was including `App\User`

There some amount of code involved so please bear with me.

Migration file

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('votes', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('value');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('users');

            $table->foreign('post_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('posts');
        });
    }
```

Route

```
Route::resource('votes', 'VotesController');
```

VotesController.php

```
public function store(Requests\VoteRequest $request)
    {
        // AJAX JSON RESPONSE
        $response = array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg' => 'Article has been posted. Redirecting now.',
        );

        if(Auth::check()){
            \Log::info(Auth::user());
            Auth::user()->votes()->create($request->all());
        } else {
                return \Response::json('Nope');
        }

        return \Response::json($response);
    }
```

Vote.php Model

```
class Vote extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'value'
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'post_id';

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function posts() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

User.php Model

```
public function votes() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vote');
    }
```

Post.php Model

```
public function votes() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vote');
    }
```

Relevant part of the View: show.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'votes', 'id' => 'votes']) !!}
    <div class="upvote topic">
      <a class="upvote" data-value="1" id="value"></a>
         <span class="count">0</span>
         <a class="downvote" data-value="-1" id="value"></a>
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.topic').upvote();

            $('#votes').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var value = $('#value').val();
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('[name="_token"]').val()
                    }
                });
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'http://localhost/laravel-5/public/votes',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: {value: value},
                    success: function( data ) {

                        //console.log(data);

                        if(data.status == 'success') {
                            alert(data.msg);

                        } else {
                            alert('error');
                            console.log(data.msg);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Try creating a model based on `$request->all()` and passing into `Auth::user()->votes()->save($myModel);`

Comment: Do you mean create a variable and store `$request->all()` in it and pass it to the `save()` method? If so, that didn't help.

Comment: No, the error you're getting is that a model is expected as the argument right? You are passing an array. So you need to create a new Model from that array and pass the Model to the save method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a whole bunch of issues here. Let's focus just on the frontend stuff for a moment. You are using the same HTML ID in multiple places, which is invalid and causing you to read the wrong element, you are using .val() when you should be using .data('value') to retrieve data from an element, and the post_id does not seem to be anywhere in your code, and definitely not included in your ajax request.

Starting with show.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'votes', 'class' => 'votes']) !!}
<div class="topic" data-post="{{ $post->id }}">
  <a class="upvote vote" data-value="1"></a>
  <span class="count">0</span>
  <a class="downvote vote" data-value="-1"></a>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Presuming you have a $post object available in that view. Otherwise you need to get the post_id from somewhere in order to include it here. Now in your Javascript:

```
$('.topic').upvote();

$('.vote').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = {value: $(this).data('value'), post_id: $(this).parent().data('post')};
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('[name="_token"]').val()
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost/laravel-5/public/votes',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: data
  });
});
```

This should at least get your POST request sending the correct data.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have `$post` object available in the view. I have updated my code with yours but I'm still getting the same sql error. It is completely ignore the `post_id` field in the insert statement. `SQL: insert into 'votes' ('value', 'user_id', 'updated_at', 'created_at') values (-1, 2, 2015-09-14 23:50:44, 2015-09-14 23:50:44)`

Comment: it worked mate, thanks a lot! I had forgotten to tell my model that `post_id` is fillable and with your js, it all worked out. Thanks.